# Как правильно удалить файл json на сервере

Tags: node.js, express

В общем нужно удалить файл на сервере! Читал и записывал модулем jsonfile! А вот удалить пробовал по всякому и `fs.remove` и `fs.unlink` - не удаляется! Подскажите плиз :)

```
router.get("/delFile", function (req, res) {
var file = 'data/myFile.json';
fs.remove(file);
res.end();
});
```

Или на сервере этот модуль удаляет другой функцией?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315138/node-js-remove-file

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!